# Changing wchar_t from 32 bit to 16bit in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, clang++, wchar-t, compiler-flags

I am porting a windows application to iOS platform. In the c++ code, the wchar_t is widely used instead of using wchar16_t or wchar32_t.

The application is coded in such a way in windows assuming the wchar_t to be 16 bit while it takes 32 bit in iOS platform. There are lot of bit operation so maintaing wchar_t in 16bit is necessary.

I have tried setting the flags -fshort-wchar to other C++ flags in project settings, but of no use. Is it need to specify the flag in any other way with some other flags?
Is there any way to typedef or redefine the wchar_t to "unsigned short" or to 16 bit for the iOS platform.

Any help will be very much appreciated.